# Running iPhone crash Logs from testers on XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4, crash-dumps

When I'm running my app on my device using XCode and I have a crash it's easy tracking where it happened on code.
However, when I deploy my ad-hoc version to testers and they have a crash, is there a way for me to load the crash on XCode as if it crashed on my computer, actually seeing the stack and the variable values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no known method to obtain a full core dump file for iOS apps that you can later load on GDB.

Are you already asking your testers to send you the crash logs? Read this otherwise:
[Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Basically:

> When the user synchronizes their device using iTunes, crash reports are
>   copied to a directory on the user's
>   computer. […]  Depending on the
>   platform, the directory is:
>
> Mac OS X:
>   ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
>
> Windows XP: C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Application
>   Data\Apple
>   Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\
>
> Windows Vista or 7:
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Apple
>   Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\

Comment: Quick question : Let's say I have my server building my ios ad-hoc distribution, which means I don't have the .dsym on my computer. If I ask my tester to send me the crashlog+binary+.dsym file , will it open with the right symbols if I put them all on the same directory ?

Comment: It's your responsibility to archive the binary (.app) and dSYM file for each version you release to testers. The dSYM files are generated by Xcode along witht the application, so the testers obviously don't have access to them. With the right binary and the dSYM in a place where Spotlight can find them, the crash logs will be automatically symbolicated when you open them in Xcode.

Comment: Not necessarily using XCode IDE. I have script running on hudson server running xcodebuild, so I was wondering if just uploading the archive to my computer as well is enough. will soptlight know to look inside the .archive file (looking for the .dsym) and know to connect it to the crash log file I got from my tester ? thanks man